# How to account for relative frequency in a generalized linear mixed model?

Tags: regression, r, biostatistics, lsmeans, glmmtmb

I have a dataset of scan sampling done on animals in intervals of 20 minutes. Each observation, an animal is categorized by category 1 (A, B, C, D, or E) and by category 2 (1, 2, 3, or 4). I am trying to determine if the animals that belong to certain classes in category 1 have a tendency to be in certain classes in category 2. So for example, I'm asking if 'A's are spending significantly more of their time in '1' than 'B's. I've also recorded the season (winter or summer) for each observation. To conduct my analysis, I created a count table that gives me a value of "n" representing the amount of individuals of each category combination for each scan (so in scan 1 I can see that there are 4 individuals who belong to the categories A and 1, and 5 individuals who belong to the category A and 2, etc ...). I then ran a generalized linear mixed model (glmm) in R which looks like this:

```r
n ~ category1 * category2 * season + 1/scan
```

`1/scan` is included as a random factor to account for auto-correlation. I ran an estimated marginal means test (`emmeans`) to determine the relationship between the three predictor variables in the model, which looks like this:

```r
((pairwise ~ category1 * category 2 * season), adjust = "Tukey")
```

However, the total observations of the different classes in category 1 differ greatly. There are around 4000 'A's, 2000 'B's, 3500 'C's, and around 400 of both 'D's and 'E's. All of the animals also have an overall preference for class '2' and '3' of category 2. I am concerned that the results of the `emmeans` test are not accounting for the relative frequency of each class in category 1, and not accounting for the general preference of all classes in category 1 for classes '2' and '3', and are instead simply reflecting the differences in the raw number of observations, which does not answer my above research question.

My question is, is there a way to add another random factor to the model or use some other method to account for the differing numbers of each class in category 1, and for the general preference for class '2' and '3' of category 2?

I have looked through some of the literature that performs similar tests but every instance I've found so far either uses individual ID as a random factor (which I don't have), or uses a chi square test, though I would like to stick with a `glmm` or other similar models if possible.

Comment: It seems strange to me that `n` is your response variable here. *"I'm asking if 'A's are spending significantly more of their time in '1' than 'B's"* sounds to me like `category 2` should be your response, using either a binomial (1 vs not 1) or multinomial (1 vs 2 vs 3 vs 4) family model.